# how to simulate mouse click using java robot without screen

Tags: java

I am now developing a programme that can simulate mouse clicking on remote vm using java robot. But if the remote connection disconnect, it failed. 
So I wanna if there is any way to do it?

Comment: If it disconnect, simply reconnect right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I hope the programme can work without remote desktop share, because we can't provide screen to so many vms.

Comment: the programme works on the remote vm, not on my own computer, i hope it can works correctly after i disconnect the remote desktop share.

Answer (score 1):

Export your robot program as `.jar` executable application then run on remote machine.

Comment: thanks, i tried but failed. the programme works on the remove vm, not on my own computer, i hope it can works correctly after i disconnect the remote desktop share.